# ServiceStack RegistrationFeature and Localized Validation messages

Tags: servicestack

I'm making use of the `RegistrationFeature Plugin` in `ServiceStack` and I'm trying to figure out how to, in the easiest way possible, make my own `ValidationException` messages (overriding the default ones). For example, when an Email Address is already in use, the `Registration` plugin returns:

```
{
    "responseStatus": {
        "errorCode": "ValidationException",
        "message": "Validation failed: \r\n -- Email already exists",
        "errors": []
    }
}
```

I would like to alter the `message` part of the emitted JSON to a more customized message. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to provide localized versions of the in-built literals used in Error Messages (we'll look at adding support in a future version) but you can still [Customize ServiceStack's Error Handling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling).

Another option is to follow the same approach taken in SocialBootstrapApi project and [override the server messages with aliases in JavaScript](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Content/js/app/ss-validation.js#L7).

Comment: This doesn't catch validation exceptions.

Comment: Hi @mythz . Has there been any update to this in recent releases ? is there a way to localize validation error messages related to registration feature ? Thanks

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah Most error messages use the [static ErrorMessages class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/5c8a1c0fde5ef024bcc44013a61b666cb5d7cca2/src/ServiceStack/LocalizedStrings.cs#L41) which you can reassign to your preferred language on startup, whilst I've converted the remaining error messages in Register/Auth Repo classes [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/18eecd67a66afd1d04d013d3a97cdad962575182) available from next release.

Comment: @mythz awesome and thank you  .. great support as usual .. i'm a ServiceStack customer will remain so for many years to come .. i'm just in love with it .. keep it up guys